# display dates as months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the number of tickets that one of my team members has worked on for a specified time frame based on months. I have the following code which shows the number of tickets for the entire time frame (from September to March). How should I modify the code to see the number of tickets per month.
Here is my code which shows the ticket ids with the actual date :

```
select distinct(t1.ticketid) as [Tickets], 
t1.BuilderAnalystID,t2.EMPFullName  from table1 as t1
inner join employee as t2
    on t1.BuilderAnalystID=t2.EmployeeID 
where 
builderanalystid='7' and
StatusID <>'12'and
cast(BuildCMPLTDT as date)>= '2017-09-01'
and cast(BuildCMPLTDT as date)< '2018-04-01'
```

I can export the entire results to Excel and create a pivot table to achieve my goal, but just wanted to know if this can be done in sql.

Here is the results that I get:
[image]

here is what I want:

[image]

the output based on the query that  Amrita Srivastava  suggested:

[image]

Comment: How about a sample data and the desired results? I suppose you know how SO works.

Comment: @Sami, added the sample

Comment: @nina_dev . . . You have one value of `BuildCMPLTDT` per row.  Which one do you choose?

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. remove the BuildCOMPLTDT Column, it will give you proper result.

Answer (score 1):

This the the basic query... You can add remove columns as per your requirements...

```
select count(ticketid), [MONTH] = datename(MM, BuildCMPLTDT ) 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY datename(MM, BuildCMPLTDT )
```

UPDATED (WITH THE SPECIFIC TIME FRAME) :

```
select count(DISTINCT ticketid), [MONTH] = datename(MM, BuildCMPLTDT ) 
FROM table1 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,compl_date) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'2017-09-01') AND CONVERT(DATE,'2018-04-01')  
GROUP BY datename(MM, BuildCMPLTDT )
```

Comment: how can I select a specific time frame?

Comment: Please use count(distinct ticketid)

Comment: You need to group by the year also, or you'll be adding the months together across years.

Comment: @AmritaSrivastava, I ran the query you wrote, it shows different rows for the same month. What I want is to display the total number of distinct ticket for a particular month .

Comment: share the screenshot of the query and output.

Comment: @nina_dev, add the year column in both - in select and in group by statement.

Comment: @Amrita Srivastava, please have a look at the screenshot. I want to see 7 as the number of tickets for the month of December and 4 tickets for the month of Feburary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff.. remove the BuildCOMPLTDT Column, it will give you proper result.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted for your query, you would use:

```
select t2.EMPFullName, year(BuildCMPLTDT), month(BuildCMPLTDT),
       count(*) as num_tickets
from table1 t1 join
     employee t2
     on t1.BuilderAnalystID = t2.EmployeeID 
where builderanalystid = 7 and  -- looks like a number so removed single quotes
      StatusID <> 12 and        -- looks like a number so removed single quotes
      BuildCMPLTDT >= '2017-09-01' and  -- `cast()` is unnecessary
      BuildCMPLTDT < '2018-04-01'
group by t1.BuilderAnalystID, t2.EMPFullName, year(BuildCMPLTDT), month(BuildCMPLTDT);
```

When you pull the month, you should pull the year as well.

Comment: @nina_dev . . . If that is the case, nothing matches the `WHERE` or `ON` conditions.